# Apache Tika Language Detection doesn't seem to work properly

Tags: python, apache-tika

I'm loading up a French text file with the sentence "Bonjour, ça va ?" using the Tika Language library for Python but it discovers 'ca' instead of 'fr'.

```
 >>> from tika import language
 >>> language.from_file('my/path/test')
 'ca'
```

I am currently using it right after `pip install tika` so with default settings.

Comment: You really need to give Apache Tika more text to go on - detection is statistically based, and 20 characters isn't enough to have any one thing show enough signal

Answer (score 1):

Catalan is quite close to French, and that phrase is the same in both languages.  Either identification is correct; Tika is doing fine ... so far.

Comment: I agree that I may need to give Tika more text, but I am not sure where you find the similarities between 'Bonjour, ça va ?' and 'Hola, com estàs?'.

Comment: Catalan includes both phrases, according to my on-line attempts to find utterances in that language.